# XML deserialization - index and length must refer to a location within the string

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

I am trying to deserialize an XML file and I'm getting an error that says:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (200, 67). ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length
```

I am using this code to deserialize the document.

```
public static object DeserializeFromXmlFile(FileInfo srcFile, Type type)
{
  XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
  using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(srcFile.FullName))
  {
    return xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
  }
}
```

It always fails on the same lines - this example is only 63 chars long but it does have two tabs before it, so I guess that makes the line 66 characters long and the deserializer is trying to read 67 characters from the line!

```
<printorder_delivery_location>FOB</printorder_delivery_location>
```

The thing that all of the failure lines have in common is that the value of the `<printorder_delivery_location>` tag is less than 10 characters. If I add additional characters (even if it's just white space) it will work fine.

```
<printorder_delivery_location>FOB Hong Kong</printorder_delivery_location>
```

I set Notepad++ to show hidden characters, and there doesn't appear to be anything amiss with the `<printorder_delivery_location>` lines.

[image: xmlimage]

As you can see there are also lines that are shorter than the `<printorder_delivery_location>` line, but these do not cause the deserializer to fail.

Anything I can check to try and resolve this?

Comment: You are not showing the model classes which are needed for the deserialization. Is there any custom serialization code there ?

Comment: Yeah there is @Dbuggy - I've posted an answer now. Silly mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sooner had I reported this that I'd figured out the problem.

The object that I was deserializing into was using the `Substring()` method to shorten `<printorder_delivery_location>` to 10 characters. In the cases where they were less than 10 characters long this was failing because, obviously, the index was out of range.

All I had to do was add in a check to verify the length of the delivery location was greater than 10 characters before attempting to get the substring.

```
[XmlElement("printorder_delivery_location")]
public string DeliveryLocation
{
  get => deliveryLocation;
  set
  {
    if (value.Length > 10)
      deliveryLocation = value.Substring(0,10).ToUpper();
    else 
      deliveryLocation = value.ToUpper();
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like it is failing a schema check.  There must be a good reason the schema is requiring 10 characters.